# Conditionally render useEffect fetch React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, use-effect

Making a video game clip posting app. I have a controller on the backend that will give me the clips in order of most commented on clips to least. I would like to switch between having the data ordered normally, to from most to least comments by using a select tag (later I will add more filters). I was hoping I could conditionally render both of the fetches based on a state from the select tag onChange, but I got an error.

```
 Line 18:5:  React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 24:5:  React Hook "useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

this is my code. Note that I was just testing it with a boolean.

```
 const boolean = true;
  if (boolean == true) {
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("/clips")
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((data) => setClipData(data));
    }, []);
  } else {
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("/most_comments")
        .then((r) => r.json())
        .then((data) => setClipData(data));
    }, []);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, you can't have `useEffect` called conditionally. Instead, call it a single time regardless, and inside that function, look to see whether you need to fetch the clips or the comments.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (boolean) {
        fetch("/clips")
            .then((r) => r.json())
            .then((data) => setClipData(data));
            // don't forget to .catch errors here
    } else {
        fetch("/most_comments")
            .then((r) => r.json())
            .then((data) => setClipData(data)); // did you mean to call setCommentsData or something here?
            // don't forget to .catch errors here
    }
}, []);
```

Comment: For some additional context, here is documentation on the rules of hooks: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level